# Why does decoding "&euro;" to "€" also turn "é" into "Ã©" in output?

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm new to Perl scripting, and I'm facing some issues in decoding a string:

```
use HTML::Entities;
my $string='Rémunération   &euro;';
$string=decode_entitie($string);
print "$string";
```

The output I get looks like `RÃ©munÃ©ration €`, when it should look like `Rémunération €`.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Your program is printing UTF-8 encoded output. `Ã` and `©` are at codepoints C3 and A9, and C3 A9 is the UTF-8 encoding for E9, which is `é`. You need to set the output encoding according to what your output device expects. Are you printing to a file, or to the terminal? What encoding do programs normally use for output? It would also help to know what computer system you're using.

Comment: Am printing in text file with UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run this version of your code (with the typo in `decode_entities` fixed, [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) mode and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) enabled, and an extra `print` added) at a terminal:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;    
use HTML::Entities;
my $string='Rémunération   &euro;';
print "$string\n";
$string=decode_entities($string);
print "$string\n";
```

you should see the following output:

```
Rémunération   &euro;
Wide character in print at test.pl line 7.
RÃ©munÃ©ration   €
```

What happens is the following chain of events:

1. Your code is written in UTF-8, but don't have [`use utf8;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) in it, so Perl is parsing your source code (and, in particular, any string literals in it) byte by byte.  Thus, the string literal `'é'` is parsed as a *two-character* string, because the UTF-8 encoding of `é` takes up two bytes.
2. Normally, this doesn't matter (much), because your `STDOUT` is also not in UTF-8 mode, and so it just takes any byte string you give it and spits it out byte by byte, and your terminal then interprets the resulting output as UTF-8 (or tries to).

   So, when you do `print 'é';` Perl thinks you're printing a two-character string in byte mode, and writes out two bytes, which just happen to make up the UTF-8 encoding of the single character `é`.
3. However, when you run your string through `decode_entities()`, it decodes the `&euro;` into an actual Unicode `€` character, which does not fit inside a single byte.
4. When you try to print the resulting string, Perl notices the "wide" `€` character.  It can't print it as a single byte, so instead, it falls back to encoding *the whole string* as UTF-8 (and emitting a warning, if you have those enabled, as you should).  But that causes the `é`s (which were already encoded, since Perl never decoded them while parsing your code) to get double-UTF8-encoded, producing the [mojibake](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) output you see.

A simple fix is to add `use utf8;` to your code, and also [set all your filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) (including `STDIN` / `STDOUT` / `STDERR`) to UTF-8 mode by default, e.g. like this:

```
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
```

With those lines prepended to the test script above, the output you get should be:

```
Rémunération   &euro;
Rémunération   €
```

Comment: I need you help for this.

I have values like this:

"Rémunération De 9.61 à 10.45 €
Secteur Contrat
IntÃ©rim Niveau d''Ã©tudes
BAC+2/3 ExpÃ©rience requise
3 annÃ©es Votre agence
NANCY Le CarrÃ© Rive Gauche -  entrÃ©e 3"

I need to insert the recored into mysql table like this; My table column is in utf8_general_ci and default character set is UTF-8 please help me from this.
"Rémunération De 9.61 à 10.45 €
Secteur Contrat
Intérim Niveau d''études
BAC+2/3 Expérience requise
3 années Votre agence
NANCY Le Carré Rive Gauche -  entrée 3"

Comment: You might want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Sure I posted it as separate question